# Condition for arc length parametrization

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm stuck with the following question:

Suppose $\beta: I \to \mathbb{E}^3$ is an arc length parametrized curve that does not contain the origin. We define a new curve $\alpha$ by $$\alpha: I \to \mathbb{E}^3: s \mapsto \alpha(s) = \frac{\beta}{\|\beta\|}.$$

I have to prove that $\alpha$ is arc length parametrized iff $\|\beta\|^2+(\|\beta\|')^2 = 1.$

This is what I have so far:

I rewrite the equation to $\beta = \|\beta\|\alpha.$ Then, I compute the derivative of both sides: $$\beta' = \|\beta\|'\alpha + \|\beta\|\alpha'.$$ Because $\beta$ is arc length parametrized, we have that $$\|\beta'\|^2 = 1 = (\|\beta\|')^2\|\alpha\|^2 + \|\beta\|^2\|\alpha'\|^2.$$ From here, I don't know how to continue. Could anyone help me please? It might be helpful that $\alpha \cdot \alpha' = 0$.

Comment: What do $\alpha^2$ and $(\alpha')^2$ mean? And why are you missing the cross-term?

Comment: With $\alpha'$, I mean $\frac{d}{dt}\alpha$. A direct computation shows that $\alpha \cdot \alpha' = 0$, so the cross term is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

We know that 
$$1 = (\|\beta\|')^2\lVert\alpha\rVert^2 + \|\beta\|^2\lVert\alpha'\rVert^2,$$
and $\lVert\alpha\rVert^2 = \frac{\lVert\beta\rVert^2}{\lVert\beta\rVert^2} = 1$, which means that
$$1 = (\|\beta\|')^2 + \|\beta\|^2\lVert\alpha'\rVert^2.$$

Suppose that $\alpha$ is arc length parametrized, so $\lVert\alpha'\rVert^2 = 1$.
Then we immediately get 
$$1 = (\|\beta\|')^2 + \|\beta\|^2.$$

Now suppose 
$$1 = (\|\beta\|')^2 + \|\beta\|^2.$$
Because 
$$1 = (\|\beta\|')^2 + \|\beta\|^2\lVert\alpha'\rVert^2$$
also holds, it must be the case that $\lVert\alpha'\rVert^2 = 1$, which means $\alpha$ is arc length parametrized.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's all clear now.